# posting search argument to another page's iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I'm looking to tweak some code on a page i didn't build. I have 2 pages, one contains a value called search name and the other is a page containing an iframe that i'm trying to target. It seems that it was originally set up to work that way and was eventually removed but not fully. I'm trying now to re-implement it.

My problem is, im not sure exactly how to post to an iframe on another page. Would i just be using a form to post to that pages iframe or javascript of some kind?

Page containing search argument:

```
click here to see:
??
<?=$search_name?>
??
```

Page containing my iframe:

```
<?php
$search_arguments = "";
if( $_REQUEST["search"] ) {
$search_arguments = "?query=" . urlencode($_REQUEST["search"]) . "&search=1";
}
?>
<iframe src="/script/dostuff.php<?=$search_arguments?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"name="search_frame"></iframe>
```

Thank You.